# How to add an immediate byte to a long register with AT&T syntax on x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, immediate-operand

From what I understand reading the Intel manuals, it should be possible to write an instruction like `add $0x7f, %ebx` and it should be encoded as `83 /0 ib` for a total of three bytes.

However, when I do this (whether I use `add`, `addb`, or `addl`) it always "promotes" the immediate value to a 32-bit value and encodes as `81 /0 id` and takes up six bytes.  The same problem exists with `adc`, `sub`, etc.  Note that I am using AT&T syntax with GNU `as`.

I have been looking for a solution for over a day and haven't found it.  Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, I don't have such a problem.

I took this assembly code produced by `gcc` (DJGPP):

```
        .file   "im.c"
.globl _x
        .section        .bss
        .p2align 2
_x:
        .space 4
        .section .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl _main
_main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        pushl   %eax
        pushl   %eax
        movl    _x, %eax
        andl    $-16, %esp
        addl    $127, %eax
        movl    %eax, _x
        movl    %ebp, %esp
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 3.3.4"
```

And compiled it with `as` and this is what I'm seeing in a.out:

```
55                push ebp
89E5              mov ebp,esp
50                push eax
50                push eax
A100000000        mov eax,[0x0]
83E4F0            and esp,byte -0x10
83C07F            add eax,byte +0x7f
A300000000        mov [0x0],eax
89EC              mov esp,ebp
31C0              xor eax,eax
5D                pop ebp
C3                ret
```

And the C program was:

```
volatile int x = 0;

int main(void)
{
  x += 0x7F;
  return 0;
}
```

Are you sure your immediate operand can be represented as an 8-bit signed integer? If it's outside the -128 to +127 range, the assembler will have to use a longer encoding.

Comment: Very strange.  I emitted all 256 variants of the immediate value on eax, ebc, ecx, and edx, and also used each mnemonic suffix (b, w, and l), and haven't gotten a single 83 encoding; they all come out as 81.  I am assembling on the latest stable Ubuntu.  Similar problems exist for the other instructions I mentioned. :/

Comment: I just retested based on your comment regarding negative values.  When I limit myself to values in the range 0-127 I get the expected results.  Thank you.

Comment: @user1084743: Ah, that's the problem. The CPU documentation says the immediate byte is treated as signed and gets sign extended before used in the ALU operation. So, even though it may seem to you that +128 or +255 only needs 1 byte, that's only true for unsigned bytes.